# reactjs how to get previous user detail with html select?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-typescript, react-tsx

I'm new to react, and looks like I'm following the tutorial with an old version of react. So, I have some users with their role, and the problem is when I want to make changes to the user role I want it to select the previous user role for preview (not the default value, in this case "admin").

[image]

> userEdit.tsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { SyntheticEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Wrapper from "../../components/Wrapper";
import { Role } from "../../models/role";

const UserEdit = (props: any) => {
    const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [last_name, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [role_id, setRoleId] = useState('');
    const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const {id} = useParams();
    


    useEffect(() => {
        (
            async () => {
                const response = await axios.get('roles');

                setRoles(response.data);


                const {data} = await axios.get(`users/${id}`);

                setFirstName(data.first_name);
                setLastName(data.last_name);
                setEmail(data.email);
                setRoleId(data.role_id);
            }
        )()
    }, [id]);

    const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await axios.put(`users/${id}`, {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            role_id
        });

        setRedirect(true)
    }

    if(redirect) {
        return <Navigate to="/users"/>
    }

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Edit user</h1>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <input className="form-control" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={first_name}  onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} required/>
                <label htmlFor="floatingInput">First Name</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"  defaultValue={last_name} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}  required/>
                <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Last Name</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" defaultValue={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} required/>
                <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Email Address</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <select className="form-control"  value={role_id} onChange={e => setRoleId(e.target.value)}>
                    {roles.map((r: Role) => {
                        return (
                            <option key={r.id} value={r.id}>{r.name}</option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>
                <label>Role</label>
                </div>
                <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>

            </form>
        </Wrapper>

    );
};

export default UserEdit;
```

As you can see I'm using "value={role_id}" to get the previous user role, but it seems to not be working. Please help me so I can continue the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

try setting defaultValue = {role_id} instead of value

Comment: thankyou for the response, but when i change to "defaultValue" it comes with a same result with "value". nothing happened